# I/O Error during ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation

I have new computer, I had on in two systems, Windows 10 and Ubuntu. Last time I downloaded some elements to SQL management studio from untrusted side and my computer becomes so much slower, and I must wait for system option about 5-10 minutes. I haven't seen anything in task manager. So, I prepared my computer for new installation both systems, I deleted all partitions, created new and install Windows again, everything went good but my computer is still slow.
When I want to install Ubuntu I have many lines of this :

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 262136
```

My question is, what should I do ? I have no idea.

Comment: There are read problems from your CD/DVD-rom. Did you try installing from usb? Your windows is installed in UEFI or legacy mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're installing from a DVD with some unreadable sectors. You need to [burn a new bootable DVD](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) and install from that. You can also [prepare a bootable USB drive](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) instead of a DVD. *Make sure that you [verify the integrity of the downloaded file](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify) to avoid random errors!*

In both case it is recommended to [verify the integrity of the installation medium](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck) (DVD or USB) which would detect unreadable and unreliable media and anything else that might have corrupted the data of the live system and the installer.

Answer (score 3):

It cat mean that your cd/dvd is damaged.

You can try to install it from usb flash. You can make it [from windows too](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the SATA mode (in my BIOS ) from IDE to AHCI and the problem solved