# Stuck with no functionality

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, desktop-environments, live-cd, xfce-panel

A few weeks back I was able to use my laptop perfectly fine with no issues. A few days later I load into Xubuntu 16.04 (I haven't updated yet). My login and background are perfectly fine but that's it. No panel or icons, and using my keyboard or right clicking to open a terminal give me nothing. I tried reinstalling with livecd but it gives an error saying "The installer encountered an unrecoverable error. A desktop session will now be run so that you may investigate the problem or try installing again." And when the session opens the icons and panels are missing from that too. After a while it goes to tty1, and then asks for Xubuntu login and I keep getting blk_update_request I/0 and SQUASHFS errors. I haven't used the os in a while cause I don't want to risk losing my data

Comment: From the description that you gave, i think it has something to do with the display manager. Refer this question below.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I/O Error during ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858082/i-o-error-during-ubuntu-installation)

Comment: @hitesh The asker is using Xubuntu presumably with Xfce, so he's not using Unity desktop environment.